# Terraform modules using a git branch as a source

Tags: git, terraform

Using Terraform modules with a git branch as a source,
I am referring to:

```
git::ssh://private_server:myport/kbf/my_repository.git//ecs-cluster?ref=v0.0.1
```

In my module source parameter, this works great and provides me with my module at tag `v0.0.1` on master.

However I'd like to specify a branch, not a tag, but am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

As mentioned in the Terraform documentation [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/sources.html#selecting-a-revision):

```
git::ssh://private_server:myport/kbf/my_repository.git//ecs-cluster?ref=myBranch
```

Comment: Is it possible to specify commit id along with branch name?

Comment: According to the linked documentation, a full commit id seems valid as well:  `source = "git::https://example.com/storage.git?ref=51d462976d84fdea54b47d80dcabbf680badcdb8"`

Answer (score 14):

You can use something like this:

```
module "test_module" {
  source = "git::ssh://bitbucketURL/my_repo.git?ref=BranchName"
}
```

bitbucketURL: Go to bitbucket UI,  check `clone URL`, copy from it.

If you are using something other then bitbucket, please refer to:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/sources.html

Comment: I believe there is a typo in your URL (double .git)

Answer (score 12):

The value of the ref argument can be any reference that would be accepted by the git checkout command, including branch and tag names.

Sample code to use the module using git tag and branch. [reference_link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/sources.html#selecting-a-revision)

In simple language: just after ref= add the tag or branch as required.

```
module "vpc" {
    source = "git::https://example.com/vpc.git?ref=v1.2.0"
}

module "vpc" {
    source = "git::https://example.com/vpc.git?ref=develop"
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Exactly the same way. You have a generic ref there that Git will work out what you mean by context assuming no collisions.

If you do have 2 refs that are ambiguous then Git will error and tell you that it's an ambiguous ref and force you to specify the full ref using `refs/heads/branch-name` or `refs/tags/tag-name`.

Comment: yes this is what i thought, I had an incorrect escape character in my branch ref so it errored. Accepting as this is the right answer ;)

Comment: Hello @krystanhonour . So how did you construct the url .
git::ssh://private_server:myport/kbf/my_repository.git//ecs-cluster?ref=branch-name ??? or

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is about private server repo, but in case someone is looking for unprefixed `github.com` urls, this works:

```
module "foo" {
  source = "github.com/org/repo//path/to/module?ref=branch-name"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like mentioned before to reference a branch in your terraform module. All you need to do is after the ref= .. instead of mentioning the tag, mention the branch name.

So.. instead of

```
module "vpc" {
source = "git::https://example.com/vpc.git?ref=v1.2.0"
}
```

which is what you use to reference a tag in that repo... use the one below

```
module "vpc" {
source = "git::https://example.com/vpc.git?ref=YourBranchName"
}
```

Hope it is clear and it makes sense.

Comment: This answer was submitted already

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried this and it is working well, even though the branch name includes a backslash.

```
source = "git::ssh://git@bitbucket.xxx.live/myrepo.git?ref=MyBranchName"
```