# Terragrunt source from specific git branch as a vairable

Tags: terraform, infrastructure-as-code, terragrunt

I know that it is possible in terragrunt to add a git source reference to a specific branch as mentioned in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52538920/terraform-modules-using-a-git-branch-as-a-source).

But is it possible to set the branch based on something like a global variable?

So instead of

```
terraform {
   source = "git::https://git.repo.modules.git//src/modules/vpc?ref=develop"
}
```

something like

```
terraform {
   source = "git::https://git.repo.modules.git//src/modules/vpc?ref=${VAR_BRANCH}"
}
```

We develop on different branches and I don't want to change every source reference when merging things to another branch.

I also read about source mapping, but it seems to me that we also have to map every single source, or did I miss something?

Thank you very much & best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code example should work, i.e. if your variable is `local` the code snippet should look like this:

```
terraform {
   source = "git::https://git.repo.modules.git//src/modules/vpc?ref=${locals.branch}"
}
```

> I also read about source mapping, but it seems to me that we also have to map every single source, or did I miss something?

Yes, that is correct. Unless you want to use the `master` branch.